# How do I pass a variable to a flow component on a Lighting page (that is NOT the recordId)?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-components, variable

I have a Flow for which I have 2 input parameters - the recordId and another Id for a lookup linked to the recordId. Adding the recordId is easy, but I have no idea how to pass the other variable.

[image]

This is the field on the object (the record of the Lightning page's recordId object)[image]

I've tried **{!Record.Application_Form__r.Id}** and **{!Record.Application_Form__c}** but neither of these work, giving me the error below. Clicking in the highlighted box doesn't give me any selection options to choose from, and scouring the web hasn't proved useful so far, as the only examples I seem to find are using the recordId as a variable.

[image]

How do I pass a variable that is not the recordId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to pass a field reference (other than record Id) from the App Builder into an input variable on the Flow.

Your *best* bet would be to [pass the entire Sobject record](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_pass_record.htm&release=226&type=5). You can do this by:

1. Creating one record variable in flow and select the checkbox "available for input"
2. On the detail record page, check the option "pass all field values from the record into this flow variable"

[image]

Now, the record is available in the flow and you can access the field value `{!yourRecordVariable.Application_Form__c}` in the flow.